# Regex for validating statement descriptor for credit card statements

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a string entered by the user to be used as the statement description on the credit card statement to describe the purchase.

The requirements are:

- Must be between 5 and 22 characters long
- Must contain at least one letter (case doesn't matter)
- Cannot contain these characters: < > \ ' "
- Only ASCII characters allowed

Here's what I've got so far, which is *kind of* working:

```
/^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,22}$/gm
```

...in that it correctly checks the length for 5-22 characters long and checks for at least one letter. However, it disallows all special characters and diacritics instead of just the few that aren't allowed. How do I modify it to allow the other allowed characters?

Comment: Try `/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?:(?![<>\\'"])[ -~]){5,22}$/i` if you mean printable ASCII chars. If you mean all of them, try `/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?:(?![<>\\'"])[\x00-\x7F]){5,22}$/i`.

Comment: `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^<>\\'"]{5,22}$/gm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?:(?![<>\\'"])[\x00-\x7F]){5,22}$/i
/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?![^<>\\'"]*[<>\\'"])[\x00-\x7F]{5,22}$/i
```

If you mean printable ASCII chars are allowed use

```
/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?:(?![<>\\'"])[ -~]){5,22}$/i
/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?![^<>\\'"]*[<>\\'"])[ -~]{5,22}$/i
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - there must be at least 1 ASCII letter in the string
- `(?:(?![<>\\'"])[ -~]){5,22}` - five to twenty-two occurrences of any printable ASCII char other than `<`, `>`, `\`, `'` and `"` (if `[\x00-\x7F]` is used, any ASCII char other than the chars in the negated character class)
- `(?![^<>\\'"]*[<>\\'"])` - no `<`, `>`, `\`, `'` and `"` allowed in the string
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a positive lookahead to assert a character and a negative lookahead to assert not to match any character listed in the character class.

For Javascript you can use the case insensitive flag `/i` and use `[a-z]`.

Edit: As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) points out, to match only ASCII characters you could use `[\x00-\x7F]` instead of using a dot.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[<>\\'"])[\x00-\x7F]{5,22}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Positive lookahead to check if there is a ASCII letter
- `(?!.*[<>\\'"])` Negative lookahead to check that there is not any of the chars in the character class
- `[\x00-\x7F]{5,22}` Match any ASCII character 5 - 22 times
- `$` End of the string

For example:

`const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[<>\\'"])[\x00-\x7F]{5,22}$/gmi;`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ST2kXh/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, I missed that requirement. In that case your answer is briljant as always +1.